# How to add a shadow for underline (bottom border) in css

Tags: css

In my case I wanted to increase the gap between text and the underline (it is hearder). So I used border-bottom property to do that.But in here I want to use text-shadow, and same shadow for the underline (which in my case is bottom border). how can I do that.

**html**

```
<h1 class="headerone">stackoverflow</h1>
```

**css**

```
h1.headerone{
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    text-shadow:0 0 5px black;
    /* text-decoration:underline; I didn't use this because gap is low */
}
```

Comment: better use rgba for shadow

Comment: if i understood correctly, you just need to add this line to your css
`box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -2px black;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

find **[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6y96tq8g/)**

```
h1.headerone{
    text-shadow:0 0 5px black;
    /* text-decoration:underline; I didn't use this because gap is low */
    position:relative;
}
h1.headerone:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-2px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:2px;
    background:#000;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this css it may help you.

```
h1.headerone{
border-bottom:2px solid black;
text-shadow:0 0 5px black;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
/* text-decoration:underline; I didn't use this because gap is low */
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lxqj2zm/)

Answer (score 0):

in css :

```
h1.headerone{
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    text-shadow:0 0 5px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1 class="shadow">stackoverflow</h1>
```

**CSS**  [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j6y3r8py/1/)

```
h1.shadow {
    text-shadow:0 0 5px black;
    max-width: 200px;
}

h1.shadow::after {
    margin-top: 20px; /* distance goes here */
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    height: 2px;
    background: black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}
```

[image]